# Are "Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions" and "Customize Application" permissions packageable?

Tags: managed-package, custom-metadata, beta-managed-package, packaging, 1gp-package

I created a beta package with the "Admin" permission set. In the packaging org the Permission Set **has** permissions `Modify Metadata Through Metadata API Functions` and `Customize Application`. 
In the test scratch org, however, the same Permission Set **does not have** these permissions. 
What might the package be missing so the Permission Set does not get these permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, there isn't a way to add system permissions into a packageable permission set. Try writing an error-handling logic.